# Contiki: How to switch between different RPL objective functions?

Tags: contiki, contiki-ng

In Contiki 3.0 it was possible to change the RPL objective function by modifying the file `Makefile.rpl`.

How to do this in Contiki 3.x or Contiki-NG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through modifying the compile-time configuration. For example, to switch from the default RPL objective function (MRHOF) to OF0, add these lines to `project-conf.h`:

```
#define RPL_CONF_OF_OCP RPL_OCP_OF0 /* tells to use OF0 for DAGs rooted at this node */
#define RPL_CONF_SUPPORTED_OFS {&rpl_of0, &rpl_mrhof} /* tells to compile in support for both OF0 and MRHOF */
```

You can then verify that you are using the selected objective function with the `viewconf` tool:

```
$ make viewconf
...
##### "RPL_CONF_OF_OCP": __________________________ == RPL_OCP_OF0
...
```